# Are prank posts allowed on April Fools day?

Tags: discussion, support

So are we allowed to post a prank question (on Meta) on the day? Is there a system that exists to allow this?

By "system" I mean something like there being a `prank` tag created; so anyone that wants to post a prank simply tags it appropriately, then at the end of the day all posts tagged with `prank` (and the tag itself) get deleted.

Comment: It's always Friday in Iceland.

Comment: I guess you missed the whole Unicoin thing?

Comment: @Stijn Yeah, I wasn't very active during that period.

Comment: It is the Stack Exchange team that pranks *us*. This year, we all got to mine Unicoins, to spend on 'upgrades' on the site. April 1st is always memorable here.

Comment: You can try... you takes your chances as with every meta question. You'll get downvoted to oblivion, upvoted to the sky or completely ignored.

Comment: I never did manage to get those fish out of my monitor.

Comment: April '15 was Stack Egg, which resulted in the feature DDoSing SE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the [april-fools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/april-fools) tag, which gets used every year without fail, despite being a meta tag that keeps getting burninated at the end of the day each year.

We can tell you as many times as we like that joke questions are not allowed because we hate fun, but let's face it, people are going to post joke questions, and then we're going to take them all down. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Is it possible to get question-banned on Meta if you post a sufficiently large number of non-serious questions that get downvoted, closed, and deleted?

Comment: @Cupcake: Only on MSE. You can never get question banned on a per-site meta, although being suspended on the main site will also prevent you from participating on meta.

Comment: `You can never get question banned on a per-site meta` Now, I know it isn't, but that _feels_ like a challenge. (First feature request? Discriminate question rankings based on user's skull shape, gender, insulin level)

Comment: Oh, where is Evan Carroll when you need him?

Comment: If an `april-fools` tag gets anually created without fail, and it is *always* burninated -- but the tag isn't blocked! -- I feel like you guys are telling us something.